# Is there any desktop application (other Gadget ) that can manage Google Bookmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, google-bookmarks

Is there any desktop application ( other Gadget ) that can manage Google Bookmarks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen a desktop application to do so.
You can however manage all your bookmarks from [google docs.](http://docs.google.com) There will be a folder called "Google Chrome" with a subfolder called "Bookmarks"

Here you can edit, view and follow all your bookmarks too.

Comment: i want a one that view it as tree